# Select only 1 group from multiple

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I have table

```
Id | Provider | Value | IsNew
```

I want to select from this table unique `Provider` and `Value` for it.

```
SELECT Provider, Value
FROM Table
GROUP BY Provider, Value
```

But I need to group by `IsNew` field also as I need to select only "New" record when Provider = '3'.

It should be something like :

```
Id | Provider | Value | IsNew
______________________________
1  | 1        | 310   | 0
______________________________
2  | 2        | 25    | 0
______________________________
3  | 3        | 250   | 0
______________________________
4  | 3        | 252   | 1
```

in result I need to select

```
Provider | Value 
_________________
1        | 310   
_________________
2        | 25    
_________________
3        | 252
```

In real example query is much more complicated, hope I explain what I want fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `isNew = 1` if it exists and otherwise the other record.

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT t.Provider, t.Value
FROM Table t
WHERE t.isNew = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Provider, t.Value
FROM Table t
WHERE t.isNew = 0 AND
      (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.Provide = t.Provide AND t2.isNew = 1);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e416/29) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I dont know if this is allowed to comment, properbly not. But god damn your fast! :)  It almost took me 2 minutes just to read the question and come up with a solution. Well done

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e416/2 something not exactly want I need... and I can't understand where is problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this with row_number:

```
    select provider, value from 
(SELECT Provider,value row_number over (partition by provider order by isnew desc) as rn
    FROM Table) a where rn=1
```

Comment: Value can be also less then "old" value, so this isn't a solution

Comment: modified query..you can try with row_number

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand it well, but it seems a pretty short query to me:

```
select provider, value
  from my_table
  where not (provider = '3' and isnew = 0)
  group by provider, value
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: this query will not count records when for provider = 3 there only one record with IsNew = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function just like how user fa06 suggested. Using common table expression in the example below to achieve the desired result

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Provider, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Provider ORDER BY IsNew DESC) 
  AS Row_Rank FROM Test 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Row_Rank = 1
```

Here is the working example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e416/19

Please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select provider,
       [value], 
       isnew
from (
    select provider,
           [value], 
           isnew,
           row_number() over (partition by Provider order by isnew desc) rn
    from test
) a where rn = 1
```

It will select only one row for each `provider`, also it will select new, if there is one thanks to `row_number` with `order by isnew desc` clause.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e416/22)

Answer (score 0):

This is my two cents:

```
SELECT a.Provider, a.Value, a.IsNew
FROM Table a LEFT JOIN Table b ON a.Provider = b.Provider AND a.IsNew <> b.IsNew
WHERE a.IsNew = 1 OR b.IsNew IS NULL
```

And the output is:

```
Provider Value IsNew
-------- ----- -----
1          310     0
2           25     0
3          252     1
```